# define unordered_map key with specific string element of struct

Tags: c++, struct, hashtable, unordered-map

I am new to unordered_map.I want define unordered_map hash table key with the specific string element of some struct which is defined below:-
The hashtable.cpp is write below:-

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 using namespace std;
 using namespace std::tr1;
    struct row{
                string state;
                int population;
            };
    struct total{
                string key;
                row value;
            };
    int main ()
    {
        total data;
        unordered_map<data.key,data.value> country;
        data.key="Australia";
        data.value.state="Canberra";
        data.value.population=12000;
      return 0;
    }
```

I got some error like this:-

```
hashtable.cpp:17: error: ‘data’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
hashtable.cpp:17: error: ‘.’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
hashtable.cpp:17: error: ‘data’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
hashtable.cpp:17: error: ‘.’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
hashtable.cpp:17: error: template argument 1 is invalid
hashtable.cpp:17: error: template argument 2 is invalid
hashtable.cpp:17: error: template argument 3 is invalid
hashtable.cpp:17: error: template argument 4 is invalid
hashtable.cpp:17: error: template argument 5 is invalid
hashtable.cpp:17: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

Comment: You need to instantiate `std::unordered_map` with types: `unordered_map<std::string,row> country`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done it the wrong way. Perhaps, the correct way to do this is

```
int main ()
{
    total data{"Australia", {"Canbeera", 12000}};
    unordered_map<std::string,row> country;
    count.insert({ data.key, { data.value } });
  return 0;
}
```

Check this [page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/) for reference

Comment: thank you for your response,But if i want define key of the struct element type of string  what i have to do

Comment: You want to define string of struct element as key?

Comment: @Raule yes as you see from above struct of total has two elements string key and row of value.So how can i define that struct of key as a key?

Comment: We are already doing that. We have `data` as struct object and `data.key` is the key there.

Comment: but it show me that the above error what i shall do?i am already defined like what you say

Answer (score 0):

> `unordered_map<data.key,data.value> country;`

what you intend is obviously what would be from c++11 and up

```
unordered_map<decltype(data.key),decltype(data.value)> country;
```

Because you use tr1 extensions anyway, I suggest you enable at least C++11 syntax for your compilation, and take what was once tr1 stuff from `std::`.